# Wrapped Key Encryption - Hide AES secret key in Javascript & Java

Tags: encryption, javascript, aes, java

I need to encrypt some sensitive fields back and forth in browser and server, same goes for decryption, for this I am planning to implement AES algorithm, but the problem here is with secret key which is exposed to the client side.

I got to know about this Envelope/Wrapped Key Encryption which used shared public key for symmetric encryption like AES.

I am totally new to this so don't know where to start, please help me implement it in both JavaScript and Java side.